# where do VHD file get there space from?

Tags: vhd

I have just created a VHD on windows server 2012 fixed space of 1GB but I am really confused to how it gets the space? Where does the 1GB come from? If I were to move the VHD to another virtual machine how does it know to take all the files in the VHD, don't understand..

Comment: Depends on the configuration of the file either its `dynamic` or `fixed`. The file can be moved in either case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you asked is a little confusing, but, I think I understand that you want to know how a file can exist of a size without actually containing any data...

VHD is basically (but not exactly) a container file (similar to ZIP/rar/others)... When you create a 1GB VHD file, it basically creates a blank file that is the size you want on the hard drive.

Files do not actually have to contain anything - a file is basically a mixture of a record describing the file (meta data/allocation table) and the data itself - so, the record may state that a file is of x size along with the location of the data - but, the data itself is simply blank.

Comment: Think you may have just made it all click. Sorry for being confusing but that's is exactly what I meant. So the VHD is really just file which can be used as a hard disk. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

When you create a VHD you are allocating space on your physical hard drive for the virtual drive. So if you have a 20GB drive, and you create a 10GB VHD, you now have a 10GB VHD, but have limited your physical drive to 10GB as well.

The VHD will store all of your files as a normal hard drive would, but it is just logical...not physical. SO it will operate in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the VHD is an actual file that can be either `fixed` where it is immediately created with the full size of your virtual hard drive, or `dynamic` where the file will grow as *empty space* is filled.  The VHD file itself behaves similarly to a physical disk drive.  If the guest OS writes data to sectors 100-120 (for example), the virtual hypervisor takes those instructions and instead of writing them to a physical disk... it writes data into the VHD file instead.